# Add colour gradient density plot R

Tags: r, plot

I have a code similar to this:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- density(x, n = 1000)
plot(y)
polygon(y,col="red")
```

However, I would also like to add a colour gradient to a density plot in basic R, particularly using a palette such as the `Spectral` from blue to red. In this way, the output would look like this:

[image]

I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `segments()` to add countless line segments with gradient colours.

```r
x <- rnorm(100)
dens <- density(x, n = 1000)
plot(dens)
segments(dens$x, 0, dens$x, dens$y, col = hcl.colors(1000, "Spectral", rev = TRUE))
polygon(dens)
```

[image]